# how to split object in 2 strings. keys in one string, values in other string

Tags: javascript, string, object

how can split object in 2 strings?.
keys in one string,
values in other string

my object is this.

```
  var obj = {
            mail: 'mailObjeto',
            nombre: 'nombreObjeto',
            apellido: 'apellidoObjeto'
  };
```

deseable output

```
string 1: "mail,nombre,apellido";
string 2:"mailObjeto,nombreObjeto,apellidoObjeto";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the latest Chrome(51 *still behind a flag though)* and Firefox(47) you can do

```js
var obj = {
  mail: 'mailObjeto',
  nombre: 'nombreObjeto',
  apellido: 'apellidoObjeto'
};

var string1 = Object.keys(obj).join();
var string2 = Object.values(obj).join();

console.log(string1);
console.log(string2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {top:0}
```

As support for `Object.values` is still somewhat lacking, here's another way

```js
var obj = {
  mail: 'mailObjeto',
  nombre: 'nombreObjeto',
  apellido: 'apellidoObjeto'
};

var string1 = Object.keys(obj);
var string2 = string1.map(function(k) { return obj[k] });

string1 = string1.join();
string2 = string2.join();

console.log(string1);
console.log(string2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {top:0}
```

Comment: you need to use `.join(',')` to join the strings with a comma.

Comment: The default is `,`, so I don't have to add the comma

Comment: @IvanParedes - you're welcome! The first works to, but it's not supported in most browsers yet, but it will be.

Answer (score 1):

Try this as well

```js
 var obj = {
            mail: 'mailObjeto',
            nombre: 'nombreObjeto',
            apellido: 'apellidoObjeto'
  };

console.log( "String 1", Object.keys( obj ).join(",") );

console.log( "String 2", Object.keys( obj ).map( function( key ){ return obj[ key ] } ).join(",") );
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
  var obj = {
            mail: 'mailObjeto',
            nombre: 'nombreObjeto',
            apellido: 'apellidoObjeto'
  };

var keys = Object.keys(obj);
var str1 = keys.join(',');
var str2 = keys.map(function(key){ return obj[key] }).join(',');

console.log(str1)
console.log(str2)
```

Look this one ;)